# Visually correct placeholder could not be found xdocreports ODT to PDF generation

Tags: typescript, templates, pdf, odt, xdocreport

### While using ODT template, We found that visually correct typescript placeholder, for example, ${val} does not work and throws the exception shown below. While **retyping** ${val}. Works!

I could be a real problem when the end users change template.

Also, I could not find the configuration to ignore placeholders which are not evaluated/replaced by the application.

**FYI**: All placeholders are populated by the application. So, I am not using incorrect placeholder values.

Is there a way to sanitize ORT content to remove a... I assume encoding issue?

*What works?*

- **Retyping** placeholder in the ODT template
- Copying working placeholder

*What does not work?*

- Changing font
- Adding or removing spaces around the placeholder
- Adding the exclamation symbol. Like: ${val!}
- etc

Exception:

```
       java.lang.RuntimeException: freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.odt.ODTReport@7286f0a!content.xml" in line 4, column 80236: Encountered "/", but was expecting one of:
<STRING_LITERAL>
<RAW_STRING>
"false"
"true"
<INTEGER>
<DECIMAL>
"."
"+"
"-"
"!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say You have an working .odt template. You open the template in MS Word and make minor changes, save and there is the error is sure to appear.

**The solution** was to **use Libre office** Saving file does not cause such issues, still it is not as convenient solution. End users are used with MS word.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue for a long time, and I followed the github [opensagres/xdocreport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/ODTDesignReport#create-field-with-oppenoffice), it works fine until now.